# Simple, fool-proof pattern to execute tasks in parallel

Tags: c++, concurrency

Assume I have a type `task_info` that stores the task-specific data needed to execute the task. A `std::vector` of those is built before executing any of the individual tasks; this build-up is done in single-thread fashion. Then the parallel task execution is set up.

To control access to the mutable resource (e.g. the output streams), I need a mutex.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class task_info{}; // fill the blanks
void execute_task(task_info info, std::mutex& mutex); // fill the blanks

void process_in_parallel(
    std::vector<task_info> task_infos,
    std::size_t threads_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
)
{
    // Never use more threads than there is work.
    threads_count = std::min(threads_count, task_infos.size());

    std::atomic_size_t task_index{ 0 }; // Note: std::atomic_size_t task_index{} is UB!
    std::mutex mutex{};
    // Every thread will do this.
    auto process = [&task_index, &task_infos, &mutex]
    {
        // The loop variable i indicates the next task to do on this thread.
        // Note: `fetch_add` is a post-increment, basically task_index++.
        for (std::size_t i; (i = task_index.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)) < task_infos.size(); )
        {
            execute_task(task_infos[i], mutex);
        }
    };
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(threads_count); // Set up the threads.
    for (auto& thread : threads) thread = std::thread{ process }; // Start the threads.
    for (auto& thread : threads) thread.join(); // Don’t forget to join the threads!
}
```

What is `std::memory_order_relaxed`? [That is a memory fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and it is concerned with the relations of changes to *multiple* atomic variables are visible to threads. As long as you have *one* atomic variable only, use `std::memory_order_relaxed` as it puts the least constraints on the optimizer. For that reason, **do not ever** use `task_index++` because it does `fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, i.e. it does what you want, but with a fence that puts unnecessary restrictions.

How to use the mutex? The mutex is locked before the resource is accessed and unlocked as soon as the thread does not use the resource anymore. In simple cases, you use a `std::lock_guard` object to lock the mutex at its initialization and unlock the mutex at its destruction.

```cpp
void execute_task(task_info info, std::mutex& mutex)
{
    // work ...
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };
        std::cout << "Task " << info.id() << " done 50%" << std::endl;
        // lock_guard unlocks mutex at the closing brace
    }
    // work ...
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };
        std::cout << "Task " << info.id() << " completed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If the little scopes are too noisy for a single line of code, one can use a comma expression:

```cpp
// work ...
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{ mutex }, std::cout << "Task " << info.id() << " done 50%" << std::endl;
// work ...
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{ mutex }, std::cout << "Task " << info.id() << " completed" << std::endl;
```

The unnamed temporary `lock_guard`’s destructor runs at the next semicolon.

If you don’t actually have a shared mutable resource, you don’t need the mutex.

If `task_infos.size() > SIZE_MAX - threads_count` the index `i` overlfows/wraps because `task_index` is incremented once for each `task_info` (loop condition is true) plus one additional time for each thread (loop condition false). Unless `threads_count` is unreasonably big or you have a gigantic number of `task_infos`, this won’t be a problem, but if it might be, it must be mitigated by `fetch_add`ing manually:

```cpp
auto process = [&task_index, &task_infos, &mutex]
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < task_infos.size(); )
    {
        if (task_index.compare_exchange_weak(i, i + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed))
            execute_task(task_infos[i], mutex);
    }
};
```

`compare_exchange_weak` is the crucial part: It compares `task_index` and `i`; if they’re equal, sets `task_index` to `i + 1` (i.e. increments it) and returns `true`; else, it sets `i` to the current value of `task_index` and returns `false`. In our case, a return value of `true`, i.e. a successful increment, means that this thread has won the race for `i` and will perform the corresponding task. A return value of `false` sets `i` to a new value, which can be of one of two categories: An index to “bargain for” or `task_infos.size()`. If it is the latter, the `for` loop condition will fail and this thread stops doing tasks. Otherwise, it’s `compare_exchange_weak` again, but with the new `i`.

About the “weak” part, it means that `compare_exchange_weak` is allowed return `false` (and not update `task_index`) even if `i` and `task_index` are equal (it may “spuriously fail” in technical terms). Because that is fine in our case, `compare_exchange_strong` is not needed.

Is my reasoning in all of this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Turn the pattern into a generic function

Your `process_in_parallel()` function only works with one specific `task_info` type and one `execute_task()` function. If you had different kinds of tasks to perform, you'd have to create multiple functions like `process_in_parallel()` as well. But in C++ we can avoid that by making `process_in_parallel()` a template:

```
template<typename TaskInfo, typename Executor>
void process_in_parallel(
    std::vector<TaskInfo> task_infos,
    Executor execute_task,
    std::size_t threads_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
) {
    …
}
```

## The standard library already provides this functionality

Since C++17 the standard library provides parallel versions of many of the [standard algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). For example, you can write:

```
class task_info {…};
void execute_task(task_info);

std::vector<task_info> tasks;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, tasks.begin(), tasks.end(), execute_task);
```

If you need a mutex as well, then you could have it as a global variable, or use lambda expressions to pass a mutex:

```
void execute_task(task_info, std::mutex&);
…
std::mutex mutex;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, tasks.begin(), tasks.end(),
              [&mutex](auto& task_info){ execute_task(task_info, mutex); });
```

Comment: You’re right about making it a template. I didn’t tag it, but the code base I’m working with is C++14. But are you sure `std::execution::par_unseq` is right? [It puts a lot of restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t), like you cannot lock a mutex or allocate memory. As far as I understand, `std::execution::par` might the right one.

Comment: You're right, it should just be `std::execution::par`.

Comment: I just tested this with GCC 12.2.0 and Clang 16.0.1 using `-O3` giving it 100 `task_info` elements: Clang does not support execution policies at all and GCC does not parallelize (as I understand, an execution policy is an optimization suggestion, not something it _must_ do).

Comment: You might need to link with the [TBB library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks) for the parallel execution policies to work as expected.